# Preventing 404 Error?

Tags: php

I'm running a PHP bot, but because the loop is taking so long it will give me a "404 Not Found" error after running for under a minute. How can I stop it from giving me this so the bot can continue running?

Comment: The CLI doesn't have a maximum execution time and would be preferred for bots anyway, if you really want a bot in PHP. But if you can't use the CLI you can set `max_execution_time` in php.ini to a higher value, or use [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Stop executing it via HTTP; run it from the commandline like any other bot
2. [`set_time_limit(0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)